# Hiding/Showing Fields Based On Radio Selection With simple_form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I have a form where I need the user to select (with radio buttons) an option that will determine the next form field beneath it. In this case, their post can be a post or a revision of a post. Thus, selecting 'post' will show a title field (to name the post) and selecting 'revision' will show a select list of existing posts to choose from (the title will be inherited).

_form.html.erb

```
<!--Form inputs-->

<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :is_revision, [[false, 'Post'] ,[true, 'Revision']], :first, :last %>
<%= f.input :revision_id, collection: @originals, :input_html => {:id => 'revision'} %>
<%= f.input :title, :input_html => { :maxlength => '50', :placeholder => 'Title', :id => 'title'} %>

<!--Javascript-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="post[is_revision]"]').on("change", function(){
    if ( $("#post_is_revision_true").attr("checked")){
        $("#title").hide();
        $("#revision").show();
    }
    if ( $("#post_is_revision_false").attr("checked")){
        $("#revision").hide();
        $("#title").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

I should mention that this works fine when hiding and showing one field, yet when selecting the other radio button nothing changes. I feel the logic is correct (although I'm not the strongest with JS) but I can't seem to get this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I made a few jQuery errors. Also, [here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3WjXZ/4/)

Try this.

```
$('input[name="post[is_revision"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $('input:checked[name="post[is_revision]"]').val();
    if(selected == 'revision') {
        $('#title').hide();
        $('#revision').show();
    } else if(selected == 'new_post') {
        $('#revision').hide();
        $('#title').show();
    }
});
```

Another way to do it, smaller but more confusing:

```
$('input[name="post[is_revision"]').change(function() {
    var is_revision = $('input:checked[name="post[is_revision]"]').val() == "revision";

    $('#title').toggle(!is_revision);
    $('#revision').toggle(is_revision);
});
```

If one will always be selected first, you could condense it to this:

```
$('input[name="post[is_revision"]').change(function() {
    $('#title').toggle();
    $('#revision').toggle();
});
```

Or for kicks and giggles and slides:

```
$('input[name="post[is_revision"]').change(function() {
    $('#title').slideToggle();
    $('#revision').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment if you have problems with any.

Comment: I gave them all a go and still nothing. I appreciate the help so far, by the way. Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with your html and javascript? That way I can see your exact html structure?

Comment: I made an edit, see if that works. Make sure to look at the jsFiddle link I posted. If it doesn't work, can I get a copy of your html?

Comment: The example in the jsFiddle worked after changing up some values!